# Eloquent ORM, how to execute SET NAMES on every query/connection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have an API which is using the Eloquent ORM. Our database uses utf8mb4 rather than utf8 so that it can store Emojis.

The problem I'm having is that I need to call the following query on the start of every connection, or else the results that are returned or in UTF8 and the Emojis appear as question marks;

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

We've tried setting this up in the MySQL Configuration but for one reason or another it's not working. We've tried using both a SUPER and non SUPER MySQL user but it doesn't make a different. The only way we can get this to work is to call the above query first before making our usual queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the charset in mysql section of `config/database.php` to utf8mb4

default

```
 'charset' => 'utf8'
```

change to

```
 'charset' => 'utf8mb4'
```

Comment: Do you mean database.php in the config folder? I don't have a database.php file, all database settings are done in the .env file.

Comment: Sorry my bad I mean in `config/database.php`